# Python setup.py file How does it work

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools, egg

I have the below setup.py file. I wanted to understand how this works i.e. how it goes about building the egg file when I run "python setup.py bdist_egg". I ask because for some reason the "endpoints.json" file is not getting copied to the egg file created finally. However if the second setup fails the "endpoints.json" file is available in the egg. How is the execution flow for setup.py?

setup.py file

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages, Extension

setup(
  name='X-py-backend',
  version='tip',
  description='X Python backend tools',
  author='meme',
  packages=find_packages('python'),
  package_dir={'': 'python'},
  data_files=[('boto', ['python/boto/endpoints.json'])],
  namespace_packages = ['br'],
  zip_safe=True,
)

setup(
  name='X-py-backend',
  version='tip',
  packages=find_packages('protobuf/target/python'),
  package_dir={'': 'protobuf/target/python'},
  namespace_packages = ['br'],
  zip_safe=True,
)
```

Comment: Did you mean to duplicate the call to ``setup()``?

Comment: See: [Packaging Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/)

Comment: As @JamesMills implied, you should only have one call to `setup()`. IMO you should read the documentation on [Distributing Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/) especially [writing the setup script](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html), [additional data](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files) and [package data](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data). If you still have questions then rephrase your question more specifically.